# Entity Framework Core - migrate and update from the code side

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I would like to ask you if it is possible to migrate and update database from the code side when the program is running (Entity Framework Core).
The problem is that i download a connection string from the Key Vault. What is more connect string can not be hardcoded or in environment variables.
Thank you for all answers.

Current error:

> The string argument 'connectionString' cannot be empty.

Comment: Is your question how to connect to a different database while the program is running? This is possible, so maybe we need to see some of the code where you're getting this error.

Comment: The question is that i need a  connectionString to the database which i get only when the program is running. But when program is running i can not update and migrate datebase using EntityFrameworkCore.

Comment: When you say "that i download a connection string from the Key Vault" do you mean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1?

Answer (score -1):

You can use an `IHostedService` to perform database migration on startup;

```cs
    public class DatabaseMigration<T> : IHostedService where T:DbContext
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        public DatabaseMigration(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var db = await scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
                await db.Database.MigrateAsync();
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    services.AddHostedService<DatabaseMigration<Context>>();
```

Answer (score -1):

I just used:

```
  using (var context = new AzureContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    context.Database.Migrate();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
```